# Get information checkbox and EditText within a LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, checkbox

I have a checkbox and EditText that generated dynamically by a query

This is the method that generates the checkbox and EditText and adds it to LinearLayout

```
private void create_form() {
    JSONObject json = null;
    int count = 0;
    lm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearMain);
    int seccion = Integer.parseInt(conf.get_id_seccion());
    int tipo_solicitud = Integer.parseInt(conf.get_tipo_solicitud());
    JSONObject jobj = obj_sqlite.get_form(seccion, tipo_solicitud);


    try {
        count = Integer.parseInt(jobj.getString("cont"));
        json = new JSONObject(jobj.getString("json"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("getParams", e.getMessage());
    }

    for (int x = 1; x <= count; x++) {

        try {
            JSONObject json_row = new JSONObject(json.getString("row" + x));

            CheckBox chb = new CheckBox(this);
            chb.setText(json_row.getString("pregunta"));
            chb.setId(json_row.getInt("pregunta_verificacion_supervision"));
            chb.setTextSize(10);
            chb.setPadding(8, 3, 8, 3);
            chb.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
            chb.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            lm.addView(chb);

            EditText et = new EditText(this);
            et.setHint("observaciones");
            et.setId(json_row.getInt("pregunta_verificacion_supervision"));
            et.setTextSize(10);
            et.setPadding(8, 3, 8, 3);
            et.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
            et.setInputType(android.text.InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_IME_MULTI_LINE);
            et.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            lm.addView(et);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("getParams", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need to get all this checkbox selected along with your EditText to keep them in the table

this is my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.php_mysql_sqlite.Formulario_verificacion_supervision" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/title_activity_preguntas_revision" android:id="@+id/textView1"/>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="285dp"
    android:layout_height="330dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearMain"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/White"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_regresar"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:onClick="regresar"
    android:text="@string/bt_regresar" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_guardar"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/bt_finalizar"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bt_finalizar"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:text="@string/bt_guardar"
    android:onClick="guardar" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_finalizar"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/bt_regresar"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bt_regresar"
    android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bt_guardar"
    android:text="@string/bt_finalizar"
    android:onClick="finalizar" />
```

and this is one image as is currently
http://i61.tinypic.com/2uo2hi8.jpg

by a method that is called on a button click, making the action to get the data

Thanks to all

PS: If you give me negative points, leave a comment of that because it has happened to me in the past and can not do wrong

Answer (score 2):

You have two options.

- Set a unique id to each checkbox and EditText and keep their ids in an ArrayList. When you want to do the check

  ```
  for(int i = 0 ; i < listOfCboxIds.size() ; ++i) {
      CheckBox cbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(listOfCboxIds.get(i));
      if(cbox.isChecked()) {
          // Do something
      }
  }
  ```
- Keep the references to CheckBoxes and EditTexts in an ArrayList and just iterate over it. This is less CPU intensive.

  ```
  List<CheckBox> yourCheckBoxes = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
  List<EditText> yourEditTexts  = new ArrayList<EditText>();


    try {
              JSONObject json_row = new JSONObject(json.getString("row" + x));

              CheckBox chb = new CheckBox(this);
              chb.setText(json_row.getString("pregunta"));
              chb.setId(json_row.getInt("pregunta_verificacion_supervision"));
              chb.setTextSize(10);
              chb.setPadding(8, 3, 8, 3);
              chb.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
              chb.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                      LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

              lm.addView(chb);

              EditText et = new EditText(this);
              et.setHint("observaciones");
              et.setId(json_row.getInt("pregunta_verificacion_supervision"));
              et.setTextSize(10);
              et.setPadding(8, 3, 8, 3);
              et.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
              et.setInputTyp
  ```

  e(android.text.InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_IME_MULTI_LINE);
              et.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                      LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

  ```
          lm.addView(et);
          yourCheckBoxes.add(chb);
          yourEditTexts.add(et);


      } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e("getParams", e.getMessage());
      }
  ```

Once you need them

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < yourCheckBoxes.size() ; ++i) {
    CheckBox cbox = (CheckBox) yourCheckBoxes.get(i);
    EditText et = (EditText) yourEditTexts.get(i);
    if(cbox.isChecked()) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Bojan Kseneman said the best option is to store your Views in a Data Structure. This could look like the following:

```
List<CheckBox> checkBoxes = new ArrayList<>();
List<EditText> editTexts = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then you add each box and editText to these Lists and later on you iterate over them like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < checkBoxes.size(); i++){
    CheckBox box = checkBoxes.get(i);
    EditText editText = editTexts.get(i);

    doSomeThingWithThem();
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: need to keep in a table that checkbox is selected along with the value of EditText @RubyDerBoos